# Порядок умножения матриц

Tags: c++

Есть такая статья, результатами которой хочу воспользоваться: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/

Программа оттуда работает правильно: https://ideone.com/5ezfkL

И вот результат работы той же самой программы, которую я пытаюсь запустить из VS 2010:

```
// Матрица Ai имеет размерность p[i-1] x p[i] для i = 1..n
int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int n)
{
    /* Для простоты программы, в m[][] одна дополнительаня строка и
       один дополнительный столбец].  Нулевая строка и нулевой столбец в m[][] не используются */
    int **m = new int* [n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i] = new int [n];

    int i, j, k, L, q;

    /* m[i,j] = минимальное число скалярных умножений, необходимое для вычисления матрицы A[i]A[i+1]...A[j] = A[i..j], где размерность A[i] равна
   p[i-1] x p[i] */

    // Стоимость равна нулю, когда умножаем одну матрицу
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        m[i][i] = 0;

    // L - длина цепочки  
    for (L=2; L<n; L++)   
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++)
        {
            j = i+L-1;
            m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            for (k=i; k<=j-1; k++)
            {
                // q = стоимость/скалярные умножения
                q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
                if (q < m[i][j])
                    m[i][j] = q;
            }
        }
    }

    return m[1][n-1];
}
```

Пример запуска программы:

```
int main(){
    const int n = 10;
    int p[n] = {10, 50, 30, 7, 25, 60, 15, 80, 55, 30};
    int cost = 0;

    cost = MatrixChainOrder(p, n);

    //std::cout << "Solution for m and s: " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "min cost: " << cost << std::endl;
    int pause;
    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

В отладчике я не смог ничего выяснить: на последних итерациях заполнения таблицы программа вдруг вылетает с нарушением доступа, и открывается какой-то файл с блокировками. Индексы, как я успел заметить, не выходят за допустимые пределы.

И еще: в функции у нас утечка памяти, потому что не удаляется динамический массив. Но удалять его нельзя, потому что нужно вернуть значение его ячейки. Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм неверен.

Рассмотрим ваш пример вызова с `n = 10`. Рассмотрим цикл

```
for (int L=2; L<n; L++)   
{
    for (int i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++)
    {
        int j = i+L-1;
        m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
        for (int k=i; k<=j-1; k++)
        {
            // q = стоимость/скалярные умножения
            int q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
            if (q < m[i][j])
                m[i][j] = q;
        }
    }
}
```

Пусть на первой итерации `L = 2`. Тогда `i` изменяется от 1 до `10 - 2 + 1 = 9`. Когда `i = 9`, `j = i + 2 - 1 = 10`. Вычисление `q` обращается к `p[j]`, то есть, к несуществующему индексу. То же относится к выражению `m[i][j]`.

---

По поводу динамического массива — почему бы не скопировать значение ячейки перед возвратом из функции во вспомогательную переменную, удалить массив, и вернуть сохранённое значение?

---

Подправил индексацию. У меня вот такой код пробегает без проблем:

```
int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int n)
{
    int **m = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i] = new int [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i][i] = 0;

    // L - длина цепочки  
    // !! у Кормена тут <=
    for (int L = 2; L <= n; L++)   
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - L + 1; i++)
        {
            int j = i + L - 1;
            m[i - 1][j - 1] = INT_MAX;
            for (int k = i; k <= j - 1; k++)
            {
                // q = стоимость/скалярные умножения
                int q = m[i - 1][k - 1] + m[k][j - 1] + p[i - 1] * p[k] * p[j];
                if (q < m[i - 1][j - 1])
                    m[i - 1][j - 1] = q;
            }
        }
    }

    int result = m[0][n - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    // добавил ещё одно значения, у Кормена там [p0..pn]
    int p[n + 1] = {10, 50, 30, 7, 25, 60, 15, 80, 55, 30, 99};
    int cost = MatrixChainOrder(p, n);

    ...
```

Проверьте, правильно ли считается `result`.

---

Возможно, правильнее будет индексировать с нуля. Переписал центральный кусок, уменьшив на 1 значения `i`, `j`, `k`:

```
int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int n)
{
    int **m = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i] = new int [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i][i] = 0;

    // L - длина цепочки  
    for (int L = 2; L <= n; L++)   
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - L + 1; i++)
        {
            int j = i + L - 1;
            m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            for (int k = i; k <= j - 1; k++)
            {
                // q = стоимость/скалярные умножения
                int q = m[i][k] + m[k + 1][j] + p[i] * p[k + 1] * p[j + 1];
                if (q < m[i][j])
                    m[i][j] = q;
            }
        }
    }

    int result = m[0][n - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Выглядит как фатальная ошибка, которую не исправить настройкой диапазона индексов. Причем это у Кормена так, реализация почти дословная. Хотя, может быть, вот это условие i<=n-L+1 как раз гарантирует, что выхода за пределы массива не будет.

Comment: @typemoon: Может, у Кормена массивы нумеруются от единицы?

Comment: Да, от единицы.

Comment: А, вот оно что! Ну тогда может быть ошибка в переносе алгоритма? Имеет смысл взять алгоритм как есть, и просто при каждом индексировании вычитать единицу.

Comment: Я именно это пытался сделать сначала. Странно, что этот способ не работает. Ведь индексы не важны, если мои матрицы m и s находятся внутри других больших матриц. Например, матрица m 7x7 находится в середине матрицы 20x20. Тогда можно не бояться выхода за пределы массивов. Код получился таким. https://ideone.com/fPxrFb

Comment: Сам алгоритм в Кормене такой: http://rghost.ru/8MG5cX7YH

Comment: У меня с работы не грузит, rghost заблокирован. Гляну из дому.

Comment: А радикал грузит? http://s018.radikal.ru/i525/1511/ae/5af5f81846e7.png

Comment: Я уже дома, сейчас гляну.

Comment: @typemoon: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Проверить сейчас не на чем, но поищу примеры входных данных в Кормене или где-нибудь в интернете. А что не так было с индексами? Почему алгоритм из книги не работал даже на матрице большего размера, чем требуется?

Comment: Ага, прочитал еще комментарии про включение верхней границы у Кормена.

Comment: @typemoon: Массив `p` был короче, нужно `n + 1`, это раз.

Comment: @typemoon: А во-вторых, я сдвинул кое-где индексы на 1. И выделяю таблицу `n` на `n`.